# How to dynamically extend the datamodel?

Tags: database, postgresql, data-modeling

I have a PostgreSQL database with one table. User of my application can add new data source (for example CSV file), to extend base data. In application user define his new data.

My question is: how to make data model for this situation?

I need create new table in database for these new data, or add new columns to the existing table? User can add more then one source of new data.

Example:

I have table of employees. User add data source with payment and data source with family information. How to store all these data in database when I don't know format of new data?

Answer (score 0):

A couple options for you.

1) Use a schema-less data store.  If you're stuck on PostgresSQL they have a json data type that will work.  Otherwise, a document database like Couchbase or MongoDB would do the trick.  That way you can add new attributes on the fly.

2) If you need to use a relational schema for some reason, use the Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) pattern.  Here's a sample of how you could add a salary and family member on the fly by inserting rows into tables 2 and 3.  (But I highly recommend option 1.)

Table 1: Employees

ID = 111, Name = "John", Date of Birth = "07/21/1987", etc.)

Table 2: Employee_Attribute

ID = 1, Name = "Salary," DataType = "Money"
 ID = 2, Name = "Family Member Name," DataType = "String"

Table 3: Employee_Attribute_Value

Employee_ID = 111, Attribute_ID = 1, Value = "78000"

Employee_ID = 111, Attribute_ID = 2, Value = "Sarah"